How can I use the full colour (with intensity and brightness, not just RGB) from a palette in VBA?
I'm trying to set colours in a vba graphing macro. I want the colour for the first two series to be the same, then the next two series to be the next colour and so on, like the following:
When I don't set the colours at all, it colours each series using the respective colour in the excel colour palette (eg "Office 2013-2022" or "Red Violet", as found under page layout → theme → colors):
I initially tried to record the colour from the first of each pair and then apply it to the next, but it seems like when vba creates a series and uses the default colors, they aren't saved as their normal colour values, but rather all as -1, with all their colour indexes set at 2.
Here I got excel to make a series, then tried to save the colour of the series in variable "colour." I then made a second series and told it to make it the color in variable "colour," but as you can see it stayed the default orange. Printing the colours and colour indexes shows that they're all -1 and 2. (Someone in staging ground also suggested that I try hex values - they are all FFFFFF)
Sub example()
Dim colour As Long
Dim colourindex As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim xdata As Range
Dim ydata As Range
Dim nseries As Series

Do Until ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop

Set xdata = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 1))
Set ydata = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(5, 2))
Set nseries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.newseries
nseries.XValues = xdata
nseries.Values = ydata
colour = nseries.MarkerForegroundColor
colourindex = nseries.MarkerForegroundColorIndex
Cells(7, 2) = nseries.MarkerForegroundColor
Cells(7, 3) = nseries.MarkerForegroundColorIndex

Set xdata = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(5, 3))
Set ydata = Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(5, 4))
Set nseries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.newseries
nseries.XValues = xdata
nseries.Values = ydata
Cells(8, 2) = nseries.MarkerForegroundColor
Cells(8, 3) = nseries.MarkerForegroundColorIndex
nseries.MarkerForegroundColor = colour
nseries.MarkerBackgroundColor = colour

Cells(9, 2) = colour
Cells(9, 3) = colourindex

End Sub

The next solution here would be to set them using colourindex values, but when I try to set them using markerforegroundcolorindex = 3 or the like, it returns only the eyemelting base rgb of the colour in the default excel set of 50-some colours, instead of the colour from the palette.
 Sub changecolour()
Dim colourindex As Long
    colourindex = 3
    Selection.MarkerForegroundColorIndex = colourindex
    Selection.MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = colourindex
End Sub

Trying to do it via the workbook.colors property yields the same result.
Sub changecolourcolors()
Selection.MarkerForegroundColor = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(3)
Selection.MarkerBackgroundColor = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(3)
End Sub

Is there a way to either record the colour of an automatically created series, or pull the actual colour from the selected palette?
As a final note, I know I can just create a colour palette with everything doubled, which is what I'm using for now, but a) it'd be nice to still get 6 distinct colors instead of just three before it starts looping, and b) I'm trying to make this macro as userfriendly as possible for my co-workers

Please include the code you tried so we can figure out where the problem is.  Setting a color using an RGB value has always worked fine for me.

What "pallete" are you talking about? Why did not edit your question and place the code  you use, as suggested in the above comment?

Apologies, I posted this and then suddenly lost internet over the weekend and was unable to update it. I will edit the the post shortly with images (I had not realized I could add those previously) as well as the relevant code.

@TimWilliams if you haven't given up completely on this post, it is now edited with code and images

@FaaneDuru if you haven't given up completely on this post, it is now edited with code and images

Try this out for example:
Sub example()
    Dim cht As Chart, ws As Worksheet, n As Long, clr As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart 'for example
    
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    
    For n = 1 To 5
        'get the color from the worksheet (see col J)
        'same color for each pair of series
        clr = ws.Cells(1 + Int((n - 1) / 2), "J").Interior.Color
        Debug.Print "series " & n, "color " & clr
        'add and format the series
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            .XValues = ws.Range("A1:A5")
            .Values = ws.Range("A1:A5").offset(0, n))
            .Name = "Test series# " & n
            .MarkerSize = 10
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = clr
            .MarkerForegroundColor = clr
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
        End With
    Next n
End Sub

My test sheet:

